# Laravel Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to fix this error. Controller.php exists in `App\Http\Controllers\`. I have tried composer dump-autoload and it did not fix it.

I have read that I would need to use artisan to give name to my app. Then it would change namespace from App\ to my app name. Should I do that?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Html\FormBuilder;
use DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
 */
public function index()
{
    return view('home');
}

public function insertform()
{
    return view('home');
}

public function insertMeasurement(Request $request) {
    $neck = $request->input('neck');
    $arm_length = $request->input('arm_length');
    $chest = $request->input('chest');
    $stomach = $request->input('stomach');
    $seat = $request->input('seat');
    $shirt_length = $request->input('shirt_length');
    $shoulder = $request->input('shoulder');
    $arm = $request->input('arm');
    $bicep = $request->input('bicep');
    $wrist = $request->input('wrist');
    $data=array("neck"=>$neck,"arm_length"=>$arm_length,"chest"=>$chest,"stomach"=>$stomach,"seat"=>$seat,
                "shirt_length"=>$shirt_length,"shoulder"=>$shoulder,"arm"=>$arm,"bicep"=>$bicep,"wrist"=>$wrist);
    DB::table('measurements')->insert($data);
    echo "Record inserted successfully.<br/>";
    echo '<a href = "/insert">Click Here</a> to go back.';
}
}
```

Comment: No need to `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` if it's the same namespace

Comment: So, do you have a file named `Controller.php` that contains a class named `Controller` (with the same namespace) in the same folder as your `HomeController`?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have a file named Controller.php that contains a class named Controller (with the same namespace) in the same folder as my HomeController.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson `<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}`

Answer (score 4):

Try `composer dump-autoload` command once.

Edit : Remove this line `class HomeController extends Controller`

and replace it with `class HomeController extends \App\Http\Controllers\Controller`

OR

`class HomeController extends App\Http\Controllers\Controller`

Comment: @prashantdeshkmukh I have tried composer dump-autoload and it did not fix it. Sorry I have forgot to write it in post, I will edit post now.

Comment: @mileom85 checkout updated answer, try both options see if it working.

Comment: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/kfzgcxf1v0k1qu9/Slika%20zaslona%202019-12-10%20u%2019.05.59.png?dl=0]

Comment: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/5uk2rl3splhehyb/Slika%20zaslona%202019-12-10%20u%2019.06.22.png?dl=0]

Comment: @prashantdeshkmukh I am giving up, I will erase everything and pull from GitHub. Start from scratch, But I have database and code which I can use again.

Answer (score 2):

there is no need for this `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` take it off, your controller should be working fine.

Comment: I have removed it and I am still getting same error. [https://www.dropbox.com/s/w8rixpsjvdovsuo/Slika%20zaslona%202019-12-08%20u%2014.55.23.png?dl=0]

Comment: Is that an editor error or do you get the same error as exception when you, for example, access the route that points to the HomeCotroller?

Answer (score 0):

Error can also occur if App/Http/Controllers/ folder does not have Controller.php file.

Make sure file exists.

Comment: file exists. I have checked.